# Angularjs Can I change $scope value of a controller from another controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an HTML div , like

```
<div id="loader-container" data-ng-controller="LoaderController" ng-show="shouldShow">
Some html design
</div>
```

And in my controller

```
angular.module('core').controller('LoaderController', ['$scope','$location', 'Authentication', '$rootScope',
function($scope,$location, Authentication, $rootScope) {
    $scope.shouldShow = true;
}
```

]);

And now, I want to hide that html div from another controller, That's why I tried to make $scope.shouldShow variable as false from another controller. So how can I make

```
$scope.shouldShow = false;
```

from another controller. Is it possible or any alternative way.?

Comment: @Claies is it...  or is it a newly generated object for each controller to use. As per the source code. I think you maybe getting confused with $rootScope?

Comment: why you don't maintain this variable inside service/factory?

Answer (score 10):

every controller will create a new Scope.

Hence the changing the scope in one controller will not reflect in the scope of other controller.

If you want to share a property across the controllers create that variable on the `$rootScope` and use it.

**In Controller**

`$scope.$root.shouldShow = true; //or false`

**In Markup**

`<div ng-show="$root.shouldShow"></div>`

Answer (score 4):

It's not a good idea to manipulate a $scope of a controller from a different controller directly. It would make your controllers very tightly coupled.

One commonly accepted way to communicate between controllers is through messages using the **publish-subscribe pattern**.

If your controllers are in completely separate components and you just need to notify the other controller, you can use the `$broadcast/$emit` and `$on` methods of the scope object to broadcast a message from one controller and listening to a specific message in a different controller. When an action happens that should change the `shouldShow` variable, you can just broadcast a message and make the other controller listen and act on it.

[Root Scope API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Another common way to communicate between controllers is by using **angular services**, acting as a mediator between controllers.

If your controllers are part of the same component/module, and you need to share state/behavior between those, then using an angular `service` to encapsulate that logic and expose it would be an OK approach (services are singletons in Angular). That would be pretty simple to implement.

However, not knowing more details about your exact requirements, it's hard to design a proper solution.

Thanks to @Callum Linington for discussing the alternatives in the comments.

Comment: This can be done more simply with services. Not just pub-sub.

Comment: Maybe. How exactly? message coupling is the loosest type of coupling, so i think communicating with messages between components has many benefits. Maybe using a service variable is simpler, but again, that means both controllers are coupled to the service. Depends what u consider maintainable and clean.

Comment: if you use `.factory(` objects are created as a singleton. So you can pass variables around like that. It does depend on the scenario, if you are using a variable in two places then you can abstract that, especially if it has logic associated with it. Rather than having logic in 2 or more places. The problem with pub-sub is it can get very hard to handle in large applications.

Comment: i know using factories and services like that is pretty common, but i don't think it's clean in all scenarios. It all depends on what you want to do.. do you need to have shared state? or do you want to notify a diff. controller (in a diff. component/module) that something has changed? I have updated my question to put some of this information in it. Thanks for suggesting the alternatives ;)

Comment: Cool, I think you definitely explained it better than I did :P